# Tomcat - Google Marketplace Click to Deploy

Tags: google-cloud-platform, debian, tomcat8, google-cloud-marketplace

I set up a VM on Google Compute Engine through the marketplace I chose the VM (Tomcat
Tomcat (Google Click to Deploy) - Open source Java Servlet container)

With the following data:

Operational system
Debian 9.11
Package Contents
Apache 2.4.25
Google-Fluentd 1.6.17
OpenJDK 1.8.0
Stackdriver-Agent 5.5.2
Tomcat 8.5.14.0

I would like to know where is the tomcat (webapps) folder where I can send my application .WAR file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `webapps` folder path is actually relative to the path defined by the `CATALINA_BASE` environment variable, as you can see documented [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/appdev/deployment.html).

In the Google Cloud Developer Console, when you access the external IP address assigned to your deployment, the default page reads:

> Tomcat8 veterans might be pleased to learn that this system instance
>   of Tomcat is installed with CATALINA_HOME in /usr/share/tomcat8 and
>   CATALINA_BASE in /var/lib/tomcat8

You'll find the `webapps` folder at `/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps`.